# Запрос на вывод профиля пользователя и подсчёт данных из другой таблицы sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

```
user_table = Table(
'user',
metadata,
Column('id', UUID, primary_key=True),
Column('email', String, unique=True, index=True),
Column('username', String, nullable=False, unique=True),
Column('hashed_password', String),
Column('is_active', Boolean, default=True),
Column('is_superuser', Boolean, default=False),
Column('is_verified', Boolean, default=False),
Column('name', String, nullable=False),
Column('surname', String, nullable=True),
Column('birthdate', DateTime, nullable=True, default=None),
Column('gender', String, nullable=True),
Column('img', String, nullable=True),
Column('reporter', Boolean, default=False),
Column('subscriber', Boolean, default=False),)

follower_table = Table(
'follower',
metadata,
Column('user_id', UUID, ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),  unique=False),
Column('follower_id', UUID, unique=False),
Column('date', DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow()),)
```

Всем привет, у меня такой вопрос, мне нужно вывести всю информацию о пользователе вместе с количеством его подписчиков, пишу разные запросы, но получается либо ошибка объединения либо алхимия не понимает какие столбцы соединять, буду премного благодарен. использую вторую версию алхимии и python 3.11